# jQuery: determine if a <li> contains a <ul>

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML code that contains nested `<ul>` elements and I need to add a class 'parent' to each `<li>` element that contains a child `<ul>`. There could be more than one element contained directly withing a single `<li>`, e.g:

```
<li>
    <a>...</a>
    <span>...</span>
    <ul>...</ul>
</li>
```

All I need is to determine if a particular `<li>` contains a `<ul>` as a child element.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will accomplish what you need:

```
$('li:has(> ul)').addClass('parent');
```

Answer (score 4):

Changed the answer after re-reading the question:

```
$("li:has(ul)").addClass("parent");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [has selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has#selector).

```
$("li:has(ul)").addClass("parent")
```