# Jquery Select UL with no LI

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can select all `ul` elements that contain an `li` using:

```
$('li:has(> ul)')
```

[jQuery: determine if a <li> contains a <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466039/jquery-determine-if-a-li-contains-a-ul)

Now, how can I select all `ul` that **do not** contain an `li`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ul elments won't contain other elements than li elements, this should do what you want:

```
$("ul:empty")
```

Comment: This would surprise me. I just got a German html reference at hand now that does not allow for direct inline/text child nodes in ul elements. Edit: Yes, uls may only contain label and li tags: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xhtml2-20040722/mod-list.html#edef_list_ul

Comment: It didn't work for me - did not catch generated empty list (there are tabs, spaces and enters between the tags) `<ul>
     
    </ul>`

Answer (score 6):

Use this code

```
$("ul:not(:has(li))")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this select li's that don't have ul's as opposed to the question asking for a selector for ul's that don't contain li's?

Answer (score 0):

This works - http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/